# "\pgfsyspdfmark{pgfid1}{8899518}{14980839}"

Tags: debugging

I copy pasted the following code and it run perfectly well. But in my main tex file, it showed the error message.Sorry I don't have the MWE because I don't know how to recreate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ctex}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
%\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
%\SetWatermarkText{保密}
%\title{{\Huge 雅思企划书}\\竞品分析，课程规划，成本及售价建议，下一步工作开展，周边产品研发等}
%\author{胡忆晨}
%\maketitle
%\section{背景介绍}
%雅思考试是由British Council, IDP, IELTS Australia 和 Cambridge Assessment English 联合主办的针对英语为非母语人士的听说读写四项英语交流能力的测试。。每年，全球有超过350万人次在140个国家和地区参加雅思考试。雅思已成为全球英语测评领导者。全球超过10,000所院校机构所认可。无论你想留学、移民、就业，还是检测英语水平；无论你想去英国、美国、加拿大、澳大利亚、新西兰，还是荷兰法国、德国、新加坡、香港等；你只需要一项英语考试—雅思考试。国内每年参加雅思的人数已经超过\href{http://www.eol.cn/english/IELTS/ielts_kuaixun/201605/t20160510_1396264.shtml}{30万}\footnote{2016年数据，现在应该远超这个数了}。 值得注意的是，由于雅思考试成绩逐渐被国内机构、公司及院校认可，因此，以自我提升，国内求职，考研考博为目的的考生占比数日益增多。雅思考生的目标分数相对集中在6分-7.5分区间内。这和大部分英联邦院校及机构对于语言成绩的要求有着密切关系。英联邦院校本科入学的基本要求为5.5分，研究生入学的基本要求为6.5分。由于半数以上考生是本科及以上学历并打算申请硕士学位，因此对6.5分的关注度最高。而对于需要就读名校的考生来说，对雅思分数的关注度则会倾向于7分以上。{\color{red}{雅思成绩有效期为两年}}
%\section{竞品分析}
%国内雅思培训机构以新东方，新航道，环球雅思，小站雅思为龙头，除此之外，各大留学机构也有自己的雅思培训课程。线上教学是近年来的一个较为显著的趋势，其中新东方在线，小站雅思为国内的佼佼者。中国以外，由雅思前主考官Alex创建的E2language也通过免费Youtube课程等形式获得了全球广大考生的青睐。除此之外，ieltsliz，ieltsonline.com等也在全球（非中国）考生中有相当的知名度。互联网教学的优势在于受众广，成本低，授课时间地点灵活，监管成本（包括隐形成本）低，抗"疫"性强等。长期看，线上教学将成为主流。不过，随着留学低龄化，雅思考试的第二大群体，10-19岁高中生阶段学生可能缺乏足够的自制力和学习力以满足线上教学的要求。此外，线上教学也未必适合所有的学生，学生和家长观念的转变也需要时间，因此线下+线上的灵活授课模式应该会是企业长期生存和发展的最佳选择。
%
%\subsection{新东方.上海}
%
%\url{http://sh.xdf.cn/}
%{\rowcolors{1}{orange}{white}
%\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%\setlength\LTright{0pt}
%
%\begin{longtable}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
%\rowcolor{blue}课程&时间&人数&收费&其他\\
%雅思预备班(雅思3.5-4）&40课次，80课时：2020/7/1 至 2020/7/11 周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30,13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00(上午训练课+下午教学课)&6-8人班，（满4人开班）（合并上课）&￥15970&寒暑或周末，同报，连报，续报有优惠（97，95，92 折)（下同)，单价：199元\\
%雅思预备班（住宿)(雅思3.5-4）&60课次，120课时：2020/8/3 至 2020/8/13 周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30,13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00(上午教学课+下午训练课)&6-8（满4人开班）（合并上课）&￥24100&单价：200.8元\\
%雅思基础班(雅思4.5分及以上)&20课次/40课时:2020/7/1 至 2020/7/11 (具体以课表为准)周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30&25-30人&￥4080&单价：102元\\
%雅思基础班（住宿)(雅思4.5分及以上)&60课次/120课时:2020/6/22 至 2020/7/9 周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30,13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00(上午训练课+下午教学课),6.25停课&6-8人,（满4人开班）&￥24100&单价：200元\\
%雅思强化班(雅思5.5分及以上)(直播）&24课次/48课时：2020/7/18 至 2020/8/23 周六日13:00-15:00,16:00-18:00&50人（满20人开班）&￥3680&单价：76.6元\\
%雅思强化班(雅思5.5分及以上）&32课次/64课时：2020/7/1 至 2020/7/18 (具体以课表为准)周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30&25-30人（满12人开班）（合并上课）&￥6500&单价：101元\\
%雅思基础班（雅思4.5分及以上）&60课次 /120课时：2020/7/13 至 2020/7/29 周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30,13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00(上午教学课+下午训练课)&6-8人（满4人开班）&￥19970&单价：166.4元\\
%雅思强化班（雅思5.5分及以上）（直播）&60课次/120课时：2020/12/5 至 2021/2/7 周六、日10:30-12:30,13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00(上午训练课+下午教学课)&6-8人（满4人开班）（合并上课）&￥22670&单价：188.9元\\
%雅思强化班(雅思5.5分及以上）(住宿）&60课次/120课时:2020/7/1 至 2020/7/23 周一至六10:30-12:30,13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00(上午训练课+下午教学课)&6-8人（满4人开班）（合并上课）&￥32000&单价：266.6元\\
%雅思冲刺班（雅思6分及以上）对剑桥雅思最新考试（剑桥13、14、15）真题的分析&32课次/64课时：2020/7/6 至 2020/7/23 (具体以课表为准)周一至六13:30-15:30,16:00-18:00&25-30人（满12人开班）（合并上课）&￥6500&每课单价：101元\\
%雅思冲刺班（雅思6分及以上）对剑桥雅思最新考试（剑桥13、14、15）真题的分析(其中四节模考课）&共计32课次 /68课时：周一至六8:00-10:00,10:30-12:30;有4天上2节课加1次模考&6-8人（满4人开班）&￥12970&每课单价:463元\\
%雅思口语写作评分标准（录播）&1课次/1课时&N/A&￥500&单价：500元\\
%雅思考试四个科目的考试介绍、题型介绍、解题方法介绍、题目常见陷阱以及如何高效备考雅思(录播）&1课次/1课时&N/A&￥200&单价：200元\\
%\end{longtable}}
%\subsubsection{其他配套服务}：无\\
%\subsubsection{周边服务}
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item 出国留学
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item 托福
%\item 雅思
%\item SAT
%\item ACT
%\item AP
%\item SSAT
%\item GRE
%\item GMAT
%\item 国际课程
%\item AEAS
%\item 院校库
%\end{enumerate}
%\item 英语学习
%\item 大学考试
%\item 中学辅导
%\item 少儿辅导
%\item 多语种
%\item 国际游学
%\end{enumerate}
%\subsubsection{试听，退课服务}
%
%
%
%\subsection{新东方在线}
%
%\url{https://www.koolearn.com/}
%
%{\rowcolors{1}{gray}{white}
%\begin{longtable}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.35\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
%\rowcolor{red}课型&课程&课时&价格&其他\\
%\multirow[c]{4}{*}{知心雅思录播课}&冲分直通车&406课时：277课时科目考点精讲精练+153课时知心智能推送+8课时/16课时/24课时(一对一）&8800-9780;12680—13580;16380—17280&一课时=半小时，6.18 88折，59课时词汇语法课99元，下同。答疑课堂18课时，全镇模考8套，作文精批26篇，外教口语20节，互动班级群，达分奖学金400元。单价：一对一约475-483每小时（低于单报）\\
%                                                  &旗舰直达班&398-430课时&4980，5380，5880&无一对一，其余同冲分直通车，有效期6个月而非8个月。单价：\\
%                                          &全科冲分班&346-377课时&2880，3280，3680&包含4套全真模考，8篇作文精批，4节外教口语，无达分奖学金\\
%                                          &单项突破班（口写听阅)&15;34;31;29&6分班599元，6.5，7分班999元&无精批，有效期60天\\
%\multirow[c]{3}{*}{雅思无忧直播课}&30天集训班（限报50人）&104h，40h直播+48小时语音语法词汇基础课录播+10小时代练+6h点睛直播&6880&送30次写作批改，15次口语模考。保持每天4-5小时，无双休。单价：66元/122元\\
%                                                      &60天稳步充分班（限报50人）&120h,40h直播+16h精讲精练+48h录播+10h代练+6h点睛直播&7880&30次作文精批+15次口语精批。每天2-3小时，无双休。单价：65元/109元\\
%                                             &单项班（听阅写口）&  16h，16h，11h，11h&   1880&写作送16篇大小作文精批，阅读送8次外教模考。单价：117元/170元\\
%\multirow[c]{2}{*}{VIP小班(6-8人）}&冲6分&145h：48小时语音语法基础录播课+1小时规划课+80小时听说读写强化直播+16小时真题技巧讲练直播+8套真题雅思全科模考&24800元&送8次口语外教批改+16次作文外教批改；一周5天，13:30-17:45，5.5周。单价：258元\\
%                                          &冲7分&129h：48小时录播+1小时规划课+64小时直播+16小时真题技巧讲解直播+8套真题模考&20800元&送8次口语外教批改+16次作文外教批改；一周5天，13:30-17:45，4.5周。单价：161元/256元\\
%雅思一对一定制课&自由定制，全科冲分，全程托管，能力预备（get ready for IELTS），单项突破等&自由定制，4小时起,建议60小时，72小时，96小时和144小时（托管）&600元每小时&考试代报名，雅思全真机考模考（含口语和作文批改）口语模考，写作单项\\
%基础\&冲刺课程（录播）&雅思词汇语法基础预备&59课时&1680&单价：28元\\
%~&雅思精准词汇&25课时&790元&~\\
%~&雅思全真在线模考\&口语+写作辅导&~&349元/次&~\\
%辅导服务包&外教一对一模考训练包A&外教模考10次&980元&~\\
%~&模考训练包B&外教模考20次&1680元&~\\
%~&模考训练包C&外教模考50次&2480元&~\\
%~&雅思写作Task2精批训练包&5篇&480元&~\\
%~&雅思写作Task1精批训练包&5篇&280元&~\\
%~&雅思考试代报名&一次&299元&~\\
%\end{longtable}}
%\subsubsection{周边服务}
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item 考研
%\item 雅思，PTE，A-Level，BEC
%\item 大学生托福 GRE GMAT
%\item 中学生托福 SAT AP 精英计划
%\item 小学，初中，高中
%\item 四级，六级，专四专八，考博
%\item 实用英语，新概念，翻译考试
%\item 日语，韩语，德语，法语，西班牙语
%\item 儿童英语启蒙
%\item 教师资格证
%\end{enumerate}
%\subsubsection{试听，退课服务}
%报名后第一堂课可退。录播课7天内可退。直播课试听课90元，录播课有不定试听。
%
%\subsection{E2language}
%
%\url{https://www.e2language.com/Course/IELTS/Academic}
%\begin{tabular}{lp{0.7\textwidth}l}
%免费账户&部分每日直播课程免费，部分练习免费，部分每日直播课免费&0\\
%青铜账户&所有的每日直播课免费，1$\times$45分钟一对一，4次写作精批，1次口语精批，模考&119USD（841元）\\
%白银账户&同上，2$\times$ 45分钟一对一，8次写作精批，4次口语精批，练习，录播视频，考前预备&199USD（1407元）\\
%黄金账户&同上，3$\times$45分钟一对一，12次写作精批，3次口语精批，练习，录播视频，考前预备，考后consultation&289USD（2043元）\\
%Express(6个月）&25节直播课，练习，录播等&59USD（417元）\\
%Express\textsuperscript{+}（6个月）&模考，25节直播课，练习，录播课\\
%口语强化&2次口语精批，25节直播，录播，练习，2次口语精批&69USD（488元）\\
%写作强化&6次写作精批，25节直播，录播，练习&69USD（488元）\\
%\end{tabular}
%周边服务：
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item 雅思
%\item PTE Academic
%\item OET
%\item TOEFL
%\item 英语学习
%\end{enumerate}
%
%\subsection{新航道}
%预备，基础，强化，冲刺，其中强化，冲刺有大班，86课时，12*6小时，20-30人小班 7，8千，小班：6到10人，24800元
%
%\subsection{环球雅思}
%大约和新东方，新航道价位一样。
%
%\subsection{IELTS online}
%暂无
%\subsection{小站雅思}
%暂无
%\subsection{嘉兴本地某机构}
%\url{http://jiaxing.gedu.org/}\\
%\begin{tabular}{llll}
%\rowcolor{blue}课程&课时&价格&其他\\
%VIP一对一&30小时:每天开班&13400&446元\\
%周末班§暑假班（10人以内）&72课时，48小时&9000左右&187元\\
%\end{tabular}\\
%周边：
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item 留学
%\item 游学
%\item 托福
%\item 青少儿英语
%\end{enumerate}
%\todo{大量死链，网站设计混乱，不专业}
%\subsubsection{退课，试听政策}
%第一天6h可退。
%
%\section{现阶段建议课程}
%\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}
%课程&形式&成本&课时&单价&售价&其他\\
%雅思一对一基础班&2h每次：中教一小时阅读+外教一小时写作；中教一小时听力+外教一小时口语&外教220元+中教120元，平均170/小时\footnote{外教220参考Greg收费，中教120到300参考环球雅思}&80h&550元/小时&48000元。赠送10节写作精批和10节口语精批&~\\
%雅思基础小班（2-8人）（两人开班）&同上&同上&80h&124元/节&9900元&单价：124元。团购每人减500元\footnote{9900,18800,26700,33600,39500,44400,48300,51200}\\
%单项班（听口阅写）（2-8人）（两人开班）&NA&口语，写作220元。听力阅读120元&20h&3600元, 2800元&20h&~\\
%口语精批（外教）&15分钟模考+15分钟讲解&110元（前雅思主考官）\textbackslash 40元(普通外教）&NA&350元§150元\\
%写作精批（外教）&NA&90元&NA&150元&~&~\\
%\end{tabular}
%\subsection{退课，试听政策}
%第一节课免费。
%\section{下一步工作开展}
%
%\begin{tikzpicture}[process/.style={rectangle,fill=orange, draw=black, text width=3cm},node distance=1cm, arrow/.style={thick,->,>=thick}]
%\node(pro1)[process]{网站设计\footnote{建议采用非改版的Winkey，vipbee的logo和出国雅思高端留学形象不符}};
%\node(pro2)[process, right=5cm of pro1]{模考软件开发};
%\node(pro3)[process, below=of pro1]{线下授课};
%\node(pro4)[process, below=of pro3]{录制课程};
%\node(pro5)[process, below=of pro4]{公众号推广,开放免费模考，线上授课, 录播课};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%
%\pagebreak
%\section{AP，A-Level竞品分析}
%
%\subsection{新东方在线}
%\begin{tabular}{lllp{0.4\textwidth}}
%课程&课时&价格&其他\\
%精讲冲5分班（录播）&42课时=21h&3980元&单价：189元\\
% 一对一直播&建议14—20次课，2h/次&~&单价：一小时 1010元；30课时 950元；60课时 920元\\
% \end{tabular}
% 
%\subsection{新航道}
%\begin{tabular}{lllp{0.4\textwidth}}
%课程&课时&价格&其他\\
%3-6人小班&40课时&11800&295\\
%一对一&NA&~&~\\
%\end{tabular}
%
%\section{AP, A-Level课程开展}
%
%\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}llll}
%课程形式&课时&价格&成本&其他\\
%一对一，外教授课+中教全程辅导&40h左右&600元/时&外教220左右+中教120元&~\\
%\end{tabular}
%\subsection{课程}
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item 微积分AB\&BC
%\item 化学
%\item 生物
%\item 统计
%\item 宏观经济
%\item 微观经济
%\item 物理C力学
%\item 物理C电磁学
%\item 心理学
%\end{enumerate}
%
%\section{下一步工作}
%招聘AP老师，录制AP纯英文课程
haha
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the code you provide does not yield any error since it just displays the text `haha`, everything else being commented out. You will have to try and provide a MWE as well as giving the error that the code produces, since here, you provide nothing to start with.

Comment: delete your .aux-file and try again.

Comment: This is normal if you have had some tikz stuff that is now delete. Some of the global positioning goes via the aux. Since tikz is now removed the  pgfsyspdfmark left in the aux is now undefined, hence the error. The solution is given by Ulrike delete the aux. Most editors have a "clean" tool to do this

Comment: Thanks@delaif. I did what you and @Ulrike Fischer told me and it worked, only for once.  So do I have to repeated delte aux files?